# Tropical geometry for high school

Tags: geometry, soft-question, education, tropical-geometry

Recently, I've found out about tropical geometry and its application in algebraic geometry. As I read about it, I thought that this would be a subject that can be taught in school as it is very simple to understand what is the tropical semiring is and what a tropical polynomial looked like since the operations are very simple.

I've found some cool application in graph theory, but I was wondering is anyone had any other applications of tropical geometry that could be interesting for high school students or even younger students? Or just any cool application of tropical geometry even in more advanced maths?

If so, I would be very interested to read your suggestions! Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tropical geometry is useful in economics e.g. for [finding certain supply/demand equilibria](https://jyu67.math.gatech.edu/slides/ARC10.pdf).

On the other hand, in my opinion, tropical curves are just geometrically beautiful enough to justify the subject for mathematically-inclined students. Of children and adults, the latter want maths to be "useful" more often than the former, it seems to me.